# Issue with IE8 and querySelectorAll() returning an element with only the opening HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, selectors-api

My webpage is not rending the content in the `<main class="page-content"></main>` tag in IE8.  I am using the **backbone.js** framework, and I have a view appending elements onto the page.  I also using html5shiv.

The first elements append just find (a navigation bar and all its elements); however, IE8 throws an error when it tries to append the `.page-content` element.  I have traced the issue to an inconsistency in jQuery's find method.  In IE8 only, when performing a `.find('.page-content')` on a DOM containing the tag, the method returns an element with the `.outerHTML` property set to `<MAIN class=page-content>`.  Notice that the closing tag (and all the inner elements) is missing.  This only happens in IE8 (I haven't tested >IE8 yet), and when it happens, it causes `appendChild()` method to fail inside jQuery's `append()` method.

I dug deeper into the jQuery's find method, and found that the source of the problem was when jQuery uses the Web API method `querySelectorAll()`. In jQuery's code, the developers commented the following:

```
// qSA works strangely on Element-rooted queries
// We can work around this by specifying an extra ID on the root
// and working up from there (Thanks to Andrew Dupont for the technique)
// IE 8 doesn't work on object elements
```

However, I don't really know what this means...

I have created a jsFiddle example to demonstrate this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/VHL7Q/6/

If you open up the jsFiddle link in IE8, an alert will display:

```
<MAIN class=page-content>
```

Alternatively, if you open the jsFiddle link in Chrome or Firefox, an alert will display:

```
<main class="page-content">
    <div class="help-toggle">
        <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
    </div>
</main>
```

Short of righting my own find method for traversing the DOM tree, I don't know how to begin solving this problem.

**NOTE:** a "band-aid" type solution that seemed to work was to replace the `<main></main>` tag with a `<div></div>` tag.  I cannot use this solution permanently however; I need help finding a way to use the `<main></main>` tag.

Comment: `main` is a custom tag. Read up on using custom tags in IE, or just use standard ones.

Comment: ...and jQuery's note that *"`qSA` works strangely on Element-rooted queries"*, should read more like *"`qSA` doesn't work they way we want, so we're changing how selectors are interpreted by modifying the selector you provided"*. The issue is that selectors are, as expected, interpreted as applying to the whole document. So if you're on a `p` element searching for a `span`, and the selector you use is `"div span"`, `qSA` will return a match of the `p` is inside a `div`, since then the `span` is also inside the `div` making the selector match.

Comment: ...jQuery changes it so that the selector is only applied against the sub-DOM structure starting with the `p` element (given the above example), so it only matches if the `div` is in fact also inside the `p`, *(which would be invalid markup, but that's beside the point)*

Comment: Thank cookie monster for helping wade through the vague comments.

Comment: I thought the main tag was an html5 tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said from the perspective of IE8, it's a custom tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that IE8 does not fully support HTML5.  In particular, it has no idea what the element `main` is.

Some of these issues can be resolved by using an [`HTML5 Shim`](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/), but I don't know if it is 100% compatible.

*Link explanation:*
(The shim, in short, runs a `document.elementCreate` for all of the new HTML5 elements to kickstart the `IE8` into realizing they exist.)

Answer (score 0):

After six days of digging, I did what I should have done on day one.  I updated my html5shiv and modernizr to their newest versions.  Specifically I updated **html5shiv** from **3.6.1** to **3.7.0**, and I updated **modernizr** from **2.5.3** to **2.7.1**.

This does not directly answer my questions about the detailed functionality of jQuery and Web API, but it can be assumed that the newest version of a library might fix your problems with a five year old software product.

Thank you Jeremy and cookie monster for your help.